# A number of questions "has been" or "have been" asked?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, quantifiers, premodifiers

Formally, is it correct to write:

> A number of questions has been asked here.

or:

> A number of questions have been asked here.

As a non-native speaker of English, I would prefer the former: the subject seems to be "number", therefore the verb ought to be singular, I'd say. However, the latter seems more common, and therefore I believe that my gut feeling is just plain wrong — but I would really like to have a definite answer.

Moreover, is it the same for "a myriad of", "a plethora of", and so on?

Comment: Related: *[Is “a total of 10 payments” singular or plural?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5588)*

Answer (score 41, accepted):

"The number" is singular. "A number", however, is plural, and takes a plural verb. Thus, for both informal and formal usage, the following is correct:

> A number of questions have been asked here.

See the usage note not quite halfway down the page at [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/number), or this [daily writing tip](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/is-number-singular-or-plural/).

Comment: Thanks for this answer; it seems to be the only one that sticks to the actual facts!

Comment: I feel like this is implying that "A number" is always plural. It would make more sense to note that in this case, "questions" is the subject, and "a number" is describing the quantity (where "a number" really means "multiple"). You could remove the "A number of" entirely and still have a valid sentence: "Questions have been asked here."

Comment: @KChaloux: that's an interesting interpretation (basically, you're saying that "a number of" is the modifier, rather than "of questions" being the modifier), but it's equally valid to remove the "questions" part: *A number have been asked here.*

Comment: Right you are. I hadn't thought if it like that, but it makes sense. Either way, I think we can agree that *have* is the correct verb.

Comment: While omitting modifiers can be helpful in analyzing a sentence, I don't think you can just drop any words you like and expect the remainder to have the same function as in the original sentence. Suppose someone wrote, "The dog next to the bushes are brown." If you drop out "the dog next to" leaving "The bushes are brown", then "are" is clearly correct, but that doesn't make the original sentence right!

Comment: Marvellous, Jay! Martha is wrong in saying that 'it's equally valid to remove the "questions" part'. _A number of_ is a compound quantifier here, replaceable (syntactically) by _several_, _many_, _seven_, _numerous_, _a lot of_ ... It isn't analytically correct to promote a quantifier / collective to the role of the subject noun it is modifying. It can be laughable semantically also: A raft of ideas has / have been assembled ---> ?!A raft has been assembled.

Comment: I'd like to tighten up the statement '"A number", however, is plural' to ' "A number", however, triggers plural agreement'. 'A number' is obviously singular in form; contrast 'There are three numbers that had cabalistic significance for the early inhabitants of Palain XII'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, excuse the necro-comment, but the phrase "a number" does not, in fact, occur in your example sentence of "There are three numbers...".

Comment: Excuse the necro-response, please. Exactly. In 'There are three numbers that had cab....', 'numbers' "is plural" ... (a) **in form** (morphology) (-s), (b) in that it requires a plural verb-form ('had'), and (c) etically (there are obviously three referents). **But** 'A number' cannot be said to be plural in form (article 'a' rather than 'some' or a numeral, and no -s inflection) (though it does mandate a plural verb-form and refers to more than 1 referent).

Comment: "A plural verb is needed after a/an (large, wide, etc.) variety of… _A variety of reasons were given._

You can use a singular or a plural verb before it: _There is/are a wide variety of patterns to choose from._

(https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/variety_1?q=variety)". 

Why is the singular verb possible only if appearing "before" the verb?

Is this some general wider aspect of the English language?

Answer (score 15):

Just looking at the words themselves, you would logically conclude that the former construction is preferable, but you're correct in observing that no one uses them that way, *because they're wrong*. Technically, yes, the subject is singular, but there are *many* phrases in English that are used to describe amount, such as "a lot", "a bunch", and "a few", which are singular but *always* used as though they were plural. It's neither colloquial nor informal to say "a number have been asked".

There is some disagreement on whether "none" should be used as singular or plural, since it was originally a contraction of the word for "not" and that for "one" or "any". Generally speaking, both "none is" and "none are" are correct, but the latter is, again, more common.

Comment: I think it is misleading to say that it is formally the former, because even if someone were writing a paper for a scientific journal they wouldn't write it that way.  There is no circumstance or situation where the singular agreement would be correct, including formal situations.

Comment: Agreed on all counts. Furthermore, the quantifiers you name ("a number", "a lot", "a bunch", etc.) are so strongly plural that they would take a plural verb even in the absence of a plural genitive of specification. *e.g.* "Someone brought cookies! A number have been eaten."

Comment: "A number... has been asked" is *incorrect*. In any context. Formally, informally, slangily, ultra-correctly, in every way you can think of, it should be *"A number ... have been asked"*.

Comment: @Kosmonaut, @Martha: You're absolutely right. I meant formally in the sense of a formal grammar, which would assume that English is typed and "a number" is always just as singular as it looks. It was unclear from context, but I did go on to say "it's neither colloquial nor informal" to use them in the plural. Editing to clarify.

Comment: +1 for the edited answer, because it addresses the probable source of the confusion.

Comment: According to several sources that I found, "a bunch" is a collective noun, so it can be either plural or singular, depending on the context. When it is referred to as a single unit, singular is used, and when the focus is on the individual parts, plural is used. See for example: https://www.learnenglish.de/grammar/nouncollective.html

Comment: Also, some sources say that there's a difference in American and British English, Americans using the singular more often with collective nouns. http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/collective-nouns