# Is the following sentence grammatically correct? It doesn't sound right

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, quantifiers

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [“A total of 10 babies is sleeping.” v.s. “A total of 10 babies are sleeping.” v.s. “Ten babies in total are sleeping.”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8545/a-total-of-10-babies-is-sleeping-v-s-a-total-of-10-babies-are-sleeping-v-s)
>   [Is “a total of 10 payments” singular or plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5588/is-a-total-of-10-payments-singular-or-plural)

> A total of 315 questionnaires was received from your area, and in particular the response to Question 10 was most positive.

Was / Were ?

Comment: Related question: [“A total of 10 babies is sleeping.” v.s. “A total of 10 babies are sleeping.” v.s. “Ten babies in total are sleeping.”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8545/a-total-of-10-babies-is-sleeping-v-s-a-total-of-10-babies-are-sleeping-v-s/8556#8556)

Comment: A total (...) was received from (...)

Comment: That's:  "A total <prepositional phrase acting as an adjective modifying 'total'> was received."

Comment: @advs89: actually, a lot of people on this page is wrong. A number of them is awfully wrong. A few of them misses the point completely.

Answer (score 3):

You can resolve two difficulties by rephrasing:

Not:

"a total of 315 questionnaires was received."

But

"We received  <s>a total of</s> 315 questionnaires."

Gets rid of the awkward wording plus it gets rid of the passive voice.

-- pete

Comment: NB In general there's no need to get rid of the passive voice (despite what many people seem to have taken from Strunk & White) - but I agree that in this case it is an improvement :)

Comment: @psmears: Should we stop obsessing, à la S&W, over the passive voice? Maybe. I notice that White's writing is admired even to this day; he seldom uses the passive voice. Strunk preached (I think) that the active voice is much stronger than the passive. Gotta' give him that one. OT: Remember this? "How many orders of beef have you passed over the counter, girl with white arms, since I've been gone? How many times have you said, 'Gravy?'" I welcome corrections and emendations.

Comment: Why "a total of?" Why not just "we received 315 questionnaires?" "a total of" is just superfluous, redundant, and -- yes! -- prolix :-)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with RiMMER: it's the singular total that the verb draws its tense from.

However it still sounds awkward. How about:

> Three-hundred and fifteen
>   questionnaires were received from your
>   area, and in particular the response
>   to Question 10 was most positive.

Comment: **the** most positive or **very** positive or just positive since there is a particular there

Comment: @mplungjan: I'd go with very myself. I was trying to leave it close to the original.

Comment: Sorry, but the verb does not draw its tense from the singular *total*. Read [Jimi Oke's answer here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8545/a-total-of-10-babies-is-sleeping-v-s-a-total-of-10-babies-are-sleeping-v-s/8556#8556).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's **a total (that) was received**, even the indefinite article asks for a singular, so "a total of 315 questionnaires was received."

Comment: Except that it's the questionnaires that were received and not the total. Questionnaires *were* received. A lot of questionnaires *were* received. A great many questionnaires *were* received. A number of questionnaires *were* received. A total of X questionnaires *were* received.

Answer (score -1):

Technically, the awkward version is correct, but it sounds funny anyway because of the proximity of "questionnaires" to "was." In spoken English you'd probably hear "were" as a result.

In such cases where the "correct" phrasing is clumsy and awkward, revise and reword accordingly. You have some good suggestions in the answers given above, e.g., "we received a total of..." etc. Avoid the passive voice unless there's some compelling reason to use it.