# Gamut - single or plural

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

So which is right:

*there **is** an entire gamut of hidden costs associated with it*  OR

*there **are** an entire gamut of hidden costs associated with it*

Comment: What does your dictionary say?

Comment: plural of course. Just not sure that it is the right usage in this context. Is it? thanks

Comment: Interesting. I can't find a single dictionary licensing 'A gamut of X are ...'. The only comment about plurality is 'singular in form' (ie _gamuts_ is not acceptable). The question hinges on whether 'a gamut of X' is acceptably treated as a compound quantifier, like 'a host of' / 'a wealth of' etc, near-synonymous with 'many'....

Comment: [Google Ngrams for 'a wealth/gamut/host of is/are'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=there+is+a+gamut+of%2Cthere+are+a+gamut+of%2Cthere+is+a+host+of%2Cthere+are+a+host+of%2Cthere+is+a+wealth+of%2Cthere+are+a+wealth+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthere%20is%20a%20gamut%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthere%20is%20a%20host%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthere%20are%20a%20host%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthere%20is%20a%20wealth%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthere%20are%20a%20wealth%20of%3B%2Cc0) seem inconclusive.

Comment: Related: [Is “a wide range of features” singular or plural?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19399/is-a-wide-range-of-features-singular-or-plural) (ie, '... Should one use a singular or plural verb-form?')

Comment: Firstly, you probably shouldn't use *entire* with gamut unless you are after a lot of emphasis. *Entire gamut* is redundantly superfluous. Gamut refers the complete range of possibilities. The usual phrase is *runs the gamut*. To say there is a gamut is pointless. There always is a gamut, the question is *is the gamut represented in this instance*. So your sentence should be recast something like *The hidden costs run the gamut*.

Comment: @Phil Sweet That's altering the sense. 'Ran the gamut' would be used to stress the diversity rather than the extent;  OP's version stresses the extent. OP's version (with the 'entire' for emphasis) sounds more idiomatic here (probably with 'there is').

Comment: Edwin Ashworth yes, i couldnt find any clear examples as well, so i guess @Phil Sweet's advice is to be followed since it makes sense. Shall rephrase.   thanks everyone!

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth yes, you are right when you say I wanted to emphasise the extent....but maybe it makes it too hard to comprehend ?

Comment: I'd use 'There is an entire catalogue of hidden costs [associated with it]'.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Yes, that works better when you want to consider them as a set. *Run the gamut* has the aspect of taking things one at a time. "The council heard proposals that ran the gamut." Gamut works best when there is an ordered set or chain of events from beginning to end.

Comment: `gamut` is a terrible choice of words here.  It means a musical scale.  _To run the gamut_ means to play an entire one-octave scale, metaphorically to try all the possibilities in a sensible order.  "A gamut of costs" is nonsense.

Comment: @Malvolio I can't agree; I wouldn't use it (as I explain above), but the 'musical scale' demand is bordering on the etymological fallacy. The more common metaphorical usage is reasonable here, with denotation _extensive range_ and connotation _wide diversity_.

Answer (score -1):

The first is correct, because the number of the verb must agree with the number of the actual subject of the sentence, which is *gamut*, whereas *hidden costs* is part of a prepositional phrase modifying *gamut*.

Comment: This has been covered so many times, and your answer shows a lack of understanding. Though _majority_ is a singular-form noun, “The majority of internet users (68%) are happy to provide personal information online” is perfectly acceptable. "A wide range of features is/are available" are both fine. Would you say 'The United States are the third largest country in the world'?