# Is the sentence "There is a large number of labourers who want to migrate to Japan for work." correct?

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement, there-is

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A number of questions “has been” or “have been” asked?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5378/a-number-of-questions-has-been-or-have-been-asked)

> There **is** a large number of labourers who want to migrate to Japan for work.

I type this sentence in a word processor, and it reports an error that "is" should be "are" (subject-verb agreement).

I doubt this is a valid error. Could anyone confirm this?

Comment: I agree. It's a possible duplicate. I'm sorry I didn't find that one.

Answer (score 12):

[This site](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/plurals.htm) has a good explanation about some of the subtleties of using collective nouns.  In particular:

> Note that "the number" is a singular collective noun. "The number of applicants **is** steadily increasing." "A number," on the other hand, is a plural form: "There are several students in the lobby. A number **are** here to see the president."

It's a peculiarity of "number" as a grouping noun.  If you had said "group" instead, then the singular would have been correct:

> There is a large group of labourers who want to migrate to Japan for work.

Comment: Here's another worthy read on the topic: http://www.slate.com/blogs/lexicon_valley/2014/04/25/a_number_of_the_phrase_is_treated_as_both_singular_and_plural_and_preceded.html

Answer (score 5):

It should be "are". The phrase "a large number of labourers", like "[a lot of labourers](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35265/a-lot-of-ideas-is-or-are)" and "a dozen labourers", is a plural construction in English and takes the verb "are".

Comment: You make a good point that there are many situations where this applies. I like your comment that argues [it depends on the context](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35265/a-lot-of-ideas-is-or-are#comment118624_37597).