# Incomplete Lists

Tags: lists, colons

I have the following sentence.

> There is a vast amount of fields to choose from: biology, computer engineering, and politics, just to name a few.

Is this grammatically correct? Is there a better way to write this?

Note that there is a list that isn't complete (hence the *"just to name a few"*). I do **not** want to use *"etc."*.

---

### Bonus

The following sentence is similar (note the end).

> There is a vast amount of fields to choose from: biology, computer engineering, and politics, just to name a few that I'm interested in.

Clearly this is an ugly sentence, so how could I write it better?

Comment: It looks correct.. whether there is a better way may be a matter of preference (especially not knowing the context). Personally I like: "There are vast amounts of fields to choose from, such as biology, computer engineering, and politics."

Comment: @Othya: Thanks, I like your suggestion; however, I'll wait for more to arrive. I hesitate to give context (in fact, the sentence was bogus, I wasn't planning to put it anywhere), because I asked this question to verify some text for an application essay I'm writing; so, I don't want to plagiarize myself (if that's possible).

Comment: EL&U is neither a proofreading service nor a writers workshop, but we can still help you if you identify a *specific* question about grammar or usage— why do you think the sentence might or might not be grammatically correct? Please take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: @choster: So, I can't learn by example?

Comment: 'There is a vast amount of fields' should read 'There are a vast number of fields'.

Comment: This usage of "amount" is very unwieldy. The more standard phrasing would be "There is a wide variety of fields to choose from". Personally, "amount" doesn't work here for me at all.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Are you sure? There is only one _"vast number"_, right?

Comment: There's only one dozen in one dozen eggs. Would you say 'There is a dozen eggs in the fridge'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Yes, of course. I'm taking about the _"are"_. Shouldn't it be _"is"_: _"there is a vast number of fields"_?

Comment: See [this thread](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51729/is-the-sentence-there-is-a-large-number-of-labourers-who-want-to-migrate-to-jap). And many others, dealing with things like 'the majority are', 'the team are / is' etc.

Comment: Honestly, I'd be fine with either "there are a dozen eggs in the fridge" or "There is a dozen eggs in the fridge" because you can see "dozen" as being a singular or plural thing... for example, if you said "six" instead of "dozen", then "are" would be correct... "There are six eggs"... odd.

Comment: @Catija: Yes, that was my reasoning for using _"is"_.

Comment: @SirJony There is no single right answer the way you have phrased the question, which makes it impossible to answer authoritatively in the StackExchange model. If you identify a specific problem with grammar or usage, however, we may be able to help. Please review the resources I linked previously.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first your sentence doesn't have the correct plurality.

> There are a vast number of fields to choose from: biology, computer engineering, and politics to name just a few that I'm interested in.

This changes a few things, are/is and word order so as to make it more correct.  Rewriting this as two sentences might sound better:

> There are a vast number of fields to choose from.  Some that interest me include: biology, computer engineering, and politics.

Comment: Hmmm, actually I suppose you were possibly correct as "amount" reads as a singular, though I'm not sure that is accurate in this case.  I would definitely rewrite it.

Comment: +1 for suggesting to split the sentence into 2. I'll wait for other answers to come, but yours seems fine, too.