# “A vast array of” is/are?

Tags: grammatical-number

Expressions like:

> A number of
>
> A lot of
>
> A host of

Are plural and thus go with **"are"** form of to be, for example:

> There **are** a number of clear contrasts.

but contrary to these, I usually see:

> There **is** a vast array of clear contrasts.
>
> And not:
>
> There **are** a vast array of clear contrasts.

In sentences, is there any rationale behind it?

Comment: Your question is a duplicate to a question (to which I contributed an answer), which itself was a duplicate of another question. IMO - you have the freedom to decide:  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/122662/grammatical-number-of-a-specified-number-of-people/122723#122723.

Comment: @Blessed Geek even if your answer to that question explain something related to my question, it doesn't mean it is a duplicate. not all people search google for "Grammatical number of “a specified number of people”"

Comment: Don't focus on my answer. It is the policy of this site, to not have duplicate questions (regardless of google search) - it does not matter how you title your question. But you are essentially asking the same question as the prior questions. This site does not appear to have a deliberate mandate of making sure people who ask questions, should ask them in a way constrained by the corporate practices of Google.

Comment: It seems to me that this website has the policy of no duplicate answers! not questions. If there is not anyone on this website who would answer my questions, I am finished using it.

Comment: I'd say either is acceptable. I'd personally go with 'there is a vast array of pictures on the long back wall of the gallery' (emphasising the display, a singular notion) but 'there were a vast array of tents of all shapes and sizes' (emphasising the individual elements).

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> There are a number of clear contrasts.
> ```
>
> but contrary to this, I usually see:
>
> ```
> There is a vast array of clear contrasts.
> ```
>
> Is there any rationale behind it?

Although the choice of singular or plural verb is ultimately up to the writer or speaker, I agree with you that your example sentences reflect what one usually sees and hears people writing and saying.

I can try to rationalize why these choices feel right to most people.  "A lot of genres" and "numerous genres" hopefully need no explanation.

"A number of" feels to most people like those two do.

"My painting collection is in the moving truck" is not in a gray area.  I think most people feel that "There is a vast **collection** of books on Churchill at the university library" is similar to the painting collection example.  Next step, "There is a vast **array** of books on Churchill at the library."  Final step, "There is a vast array of clear contrasts."

So, we're treating *array of clear contrasts* as a singular noun with a prepositional phrase.

If I didn't understand which aspect you'd like explained, please write a comment.