# Concord of "scholarly enquiry combined with introspection"

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

What is correct:

> - Scholarly enquiry combined with introspection reveals
> - Scholarly enquiry combined with introspection reveal

Comment: Does [this "combined with" question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/123330) answer this?

Answer (score 1):

The subject is *scholarly enqiry*, singular. *Combined with introspection* modifies it, but doesn't make it plural, so singular *reveals* is what you want.