# "All previous work is" or "All previous work are"

Tags: grammar

Which of the following two sentences is the correct one?

(1) All previous work is in the file.

(2) All previous work are in the file.

Google search turned up documents using both forms, but the "is" form was most prevalent.

Thanks.

Comment: There are several past threads on number with collective and mass nouns which may be of interest; see e.g. *[“A variety of X is” vs. “a variety of X are”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44942)*, *[A number of questions “has been” or “have been” asked?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5378)*, *[“There’s” or “There are”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77089)*, and *[Are collective nouns always plural, or are certain ones singular?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence is correct:

> All previous work is in the file.

"Work" is an uncountable noun when used with this meaning, and thus should be treated as singular, meaning "is" is the correct verb here.

Comment: Put more simply, _work_ is singular number; _works_ is plural number. Verbs agree with their subjects in number.