# Was/were plural

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, there-is, verb-agreement

Trying to write a report for my work, I know that if I reconstructed this sentence it would be "were", but with the way it is written now, which way would be right?

> 1. There **was** a total of 652 responses in the box.

OR

> 2. There **were** a total of 652 responses in the box.

Comment: Why do you think only one of those would be “right”?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5588/is-a-total-of-10-payments-singular-or-plural or http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5378/a-number-of-questions-has-been-or-have-been-asked

Answer (score 1):

> There was a total of 652 responses in the box.

This is correct, because a "total" is a singular entity, not a plural one. Your second example would be correct as so:

> There were 652 responses in the box (in total).