# "A number of students" vs. "the number of students"

Tags: meaning, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A number of questions “has been” or “have been” asked?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5378/a-number-of-questions-has-been-or-have-been-asked)

From the grammatical view both are correct, but please explain the difference in meaning:

1. The number of students in the class **is** fifteen.
2. A number of students **were** late for class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The number of students in the class is fifteen.

The verb is singular because it refers to 'the number'. The subject of this sentence is 'the number'. 'Of students' is a modifier of 'the number'

'A number of' means several, some.

> Several students were late for class.
>
> Some students were late for class.
>
> A number of students were late for class.

The subject of these sentences is 'students', and 'some', 'several', 'a number of' are modifiers of 'students'. The verb agrees with the subject.

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence informs you about the `number` which is singular

> The number is fifteen

The second one is about the `students` which is plural word

> Students were late