# Does "the same number of people" behave as singular or plural?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, verb-agreement

This hurts my eyes to read it and my ears to say it, but the writer stands by [item #43](http://www.fool.com/investing/general/2012/04/05/50-amazing-numbers-about-todays-economy-.aspx?source=ihpsitth0000001)

> About the same number of people was awarded bachelor's degrees in 2010 as filed for personal bankruptcy (1.6 million).

Is the subject in this sentence singular or plural?

Comment: Related: [“A number of students” vs “The number of students”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59753/a-number-of-students-vs-the-number-of-students)

Comment: Related too: [A number of questions “has been” or “have been” asked?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5378/a-number-of-questions-has-been-or-have-been-asked)

Comment: I read those questions too and believe this one is subtly different: "The same number of students...as..." verses "The number of students"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The heading for paragraph 7 of Harbrace College Handbook, Chapter 6a states,

> **When regarded as a unit, collective nouns, as well as noun phrases denoting quantity, take singular verbs.**
>   . . .
>   *The number* is singular; a *number* is plural.
>   "The number of students *was* small." [The *number* is taken as a unit.]
>   "A number of students *were taking* tests." [A *number* refers to individuals.]

Their examples indicate that it's different depending on if the number is taken as a unit or refers to individuals.  In your case I think it's individuals and should use the plural.

Answer (score 6):

In the sentence

> About the same number of people was awarded bachelor's degrees in 2010 as filed for personal bankruptcy (1.6 million).

the verb should be *were*. Who was awarded the bachelor's degree? Not the *number* but the *people*.

If the sentence were:

> About the same number of people is expected to show up for this party as did for the previous one.

then the verb *is* could be used, because *the same number* is what is being expected. (Although *are* could be used as well, because the people are also being expected.)

Comment: While I was searching for "the same number of people" on Google, I came upon your answer. Since you've also commented on my related question, I'd like to ask you why you'd say "_the same number_ is what is being expected (in the second part of the answer). If _number_ is being expected, you should be able to say _The number of people is expected to show up_, which I don't think you can. And in a similar sentence _Many people are expected to show up_, it's _people_ that are expected, isn't it?