# "Number of attempts per question is unlimited" or "are limited"?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, quantifiers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“A number of students” vs. “the number of students”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59753/a-number-of-students-vs-the-number-of-students)

I want to know whether the following construct is correct:

> Number of Attempts per Question is unlimited.

I want to know if it should be *are* in place of *is* in the above sentence.

I have read somewhere that the article before *number* (whether *the* or *a)* governs the form of the verb. However, here there is no article before *Number*.

Comment: From the *title* alone a better duplicate is *[A number of questions "has been" or "have been" asked?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5378/)*

Answer (score 1):

Follow *the number of* with a singular verb, and *a number of* with a plural verb. The grammatical reason is that in the first case *number* is the head of the subject phrase, but in the second case it’s a premodifying element. In the context in which your example is likely to occur, *number* will probably be definite, with an ellipsed *the*, so the singular verb would be appropriate.