# "The maximum number": plural or singular?

Tags: grammatical-number

Kindly, what are your thoughts on the following sentences:

> 1. The maximum number of wordbooks (%d) have been saved.
> 2. The maximum number of wordbooks (%d) has been saved.

My opinion is that (1) is more appropriate as "save" relates to wordbooks (a plural noun) and "The ... number" is some kind of determiner.

The dissenting opinion is that "The number" is obviously singular, and the "wordbooks" are subsidiary.

I agree that (2) is grammatically correct but I maintain it implies merely a single number was saved, not the wordbooks themselves.

Comment: Related: [“A number of students” vs. “the number of students”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59753/a-number-of-students-vs-the-number-of-students) and the many questions linked from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in ‘The Cambridge Guide to English Usage, when *number of* is preceded by *the*, it is the head (the most important word) of the phrase ‘the number of  . . .’ It is singular, and so requires a singular verb.

The case is different when *number of* is preceded by *a*. Then, it is a pre-modifying element, leaving the number of the verb to determined by the number of the following head word (*wordbooks* in your example), which will invariably be plural.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.
Does anyone agree with me that 2) is incorrect in meaning, though?

"A number of cars are driven daily", OK, but what about

"The largest number of cars is driven daily" ?

Comment: @Oscar. It’s possible to make up all sorts of combinations, but we can really only draw sensible conclusions from authentic examples shown in context. For example, in what circumstances would anyone want to say _The largest number of cars is driven daily_ rather than _Most cars are driven daily_?

Comment: @Susan. Well, _number of_ is a phrase and _of_ is a preposition, but _the / a number of_ might best be seen as a lexical unit performing the function of a determiner.