# Maximum number of minutes is/are 60

Tags: grammatical-number

I saw a sentence like:

> Maximum number of minutes are 60

but I feel like it must be "**is 60**" not "**are**" as we are describing about the word **number** here which is singular.

and after search I came across two different questions with two different answers ([1](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/141306/the-maximum-number-plural-or-singular) , [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/141306/the-maximum-number-plural-or-singular)) and I don't know what exactly is the correct behavior here and if I'm able to use both of them or not.

Comment: Link 2 is the same as Link 1. But Link 1 seems the definitive answer anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is*.  It's easier to use your ear if you leave the prepositional phrase off, which makes this "number is" versus "number are".  The prepositional phrase "of minutes" doesn't change the plurality.  *Number* is [singular](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/is-number-singular-or-plural/).