# "The number of students are larger" vs. "The number of students is larger"

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

What is the correct verb to use, is it *is* or *are*?

A) The number of students **are** larger than before.
B) The number of students **is** larger than before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A number of questions "has been" or "have been" asked?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5378/a-number-of-questions-has-been-or-have-been-asked) and also of [“A number of students” vs. “the number of students”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59753/a-number-of-students-vs-the-number-of-students) (which is closed as a duplicate of the former)

Answer (score 2):

Compare these examples:

> [1] ***A number*** of students **were** arrested.
>
> [2] ***The number*** of students arrested **has** not been revealed.

In [1] the indefinite article "a" indicates an imprecise number and is said to be number-transparent in that the number of the whole NP is determined not by the head but by the noun that is complement to "of". As it happens, in this use "number" selects plural nouns as complement to "of", so the verb is always plural.

In [2] the definite article "the" represents a precise number and hence the subject NP is singular by virtue of having singular non-transparent "number" as head.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the *singular* verb "is", because "*the* number" (as opposed to just "a number") makes the number, rather than the students, the subject.

As an aside, it is more common to use "greater" than "larger", especially when *comparing* numbers, as you are. I would phrase it as:

> The number of students is greater than before.

Comment: So, according to this answer I can say ...“*A number* of students **is** at home with the flu”? Because in the answer it says `"a number" is singular`.