# Increase Vs Increases

Tags: grammar

I'm in an argument with somebody, about this line.
The number of customers increase vs The number of customers increases.
We are focusing on the number, but the subject is plural.
He's arguing that the subject is "number"
I'm arguing that it's "customers"

What would be grammatically correct? If there is a correct way, is there any references on it?

Comment: Let's hear the whole sentence, please. Customers don't increase, though their number or numbers might. It's not a good idea to decide "My subject is *number*, but my focus is *customer*, so my verb will agree with that."

Comment: Why do you think the subject is *customers*? The subject is *number,* but to give an answer that resolves your confusion, I'd need to know the source of it.

Comment: Seems to have been asked many times and either is possible, e.g. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59753/a-number-of-students-vs-the-number-of-students (not sure which is the best/original).

Comment: We do use notional agreement in some cases (e.g. *A number of customers were sad*, where the verb agrees with the object of the preposition), but that doesn’t happen with *the number*.

Comment: 'The number of Ns' (N a suitable count noun usage, Ns the plural form) indeed centres on singular 'number' when it comes to deciding verb form to follow. Compare 'the tally of children needing such care **is** increasing'; 'the count of diabetes mellitus patients **is** increasing'. // With 'a number of Ns', however, 'a number of' is a compound quantifier and is 'number-transparent' for verb agreement purposes (ie verb agreement now hinges on the fact that Ns is plural). 'A number of children **are** in need of such care.' Compare 'A lot of / A majority of / Many / Several men **were** asleep.