# Use "have" or "has" any/anyone/anything in the question?

Tags: grammatical-number, questions, verb-agreement

Similar to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/5378/13045), is it correct to use `have` or `has` with any* (any/anything/anyone/...) in a question?

Examples:

- Have/Has any of my advices help you?
- Have/Has anyone of you seen it?

Does it depend on the context, or is there a general rule?

Comment: Questions have the exact same rules for verb agreement as statements. The fact that it's a question has no relevance at all.

Comment: Actually, the fact that it's a question allows the use of _any_ and other NPIs: the related statement _*Anyone has seen it_ is ungrammatical.

Comment: @JohnLawler good point. It doesn't, however, have any direct relevance to verb agreement.

Comment: Very little does, after all. Verb agreement only occurs in one person, one number, and one tense in English, and only on the first verb in a phrase. It's pretty moribund, and very broadly mis-taught and mis-learned in schools, so we get **way** too many questions about it.

Comment: _Anyone_ and _anything_ are pronouns taking singular agreement. _Any_ (in the sense under discussion) is a determiner used to reference singular, plural and mass nouns: Has any pupil managed to solve this? // Is there any rice left? // Have any birds landed yet?

Answer (score 13):

The first one (once the verb tense is corrected, and substituting a count noun for *advice*, which is a mass noun) allows either, with very slightly different meaning:

> Have any of my suggestions helped you?
>
> Has any of my suggestions helped you?

The first seems more natural to me; but the second is possible, and implies that only one of them could have helped.

But *anyone* is syntactically singular, so

> Has anyone seen it?

is natural, not **have anyone seen it?*. (*Anyone* is not necessarily singular in meaning, so the answer might refer to one person or several).

(I have left out *of you* because **anyone of you* is not idiomatic. *Any one of you* is idiomatic, but that means specifically just **one** of you.)