# "Becomes" or "Become" in this sentence?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

> Many small companies have difficulty growing because the number of
>   orders becomes too large to handle.

Should I use *become* or *becomes* in this sentence? I don't know, but the sentence feels a little odd to me.

Comment: It's correct. **Becomes** refers to **number** and not **orders**. **Number** is singular, so the word describing it should be plural, hence **becomes**.

Comment: Thanks! Can you reply with an answer below so I can mark it as the answer?

Comment: As this has been answered here before, an answer would not be appropriate.

Comment: Answered before at [A number of questions "has been" or "have been" asked?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5378/a-number-of-questions-has-been-or-have-been-asked) (see Martha's answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Many small companies have difficulty growing because the number of
>   orders becomes too large to handle.

In your sentence, you need to see what exactly is **becomes** describing. Whether you should use "*become*" or "*becomes*" depends on what the word intends to describe- **number** or **orders**.

> because the number of orders becomes too large to handle

Here, *becomes* refers to *number*. *Number* is used as singular here, so you should use *becomes*.

When you intend to refer to *orders* instead, that is when you would use *become*, as in this (hypothetical) example:

> Many small companies have difficulty growing because their orders
>   become too large to handle.

Also take a look at [this](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp) and [this](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/sv_agr.htm). They describe some basic rules to help deal with similar sentences.

Comment: But that would change the meaning. It would mean that the size of individual orders become too large. What the OP wants to say is that the number of orders has become too large. They are two quite different things.

Comment: I agree, which is why I said **hypothetical** example. The intent is to explain to OP that **number** of orders is described by **becomes**, and in some other context, **orders** would be described by **become**. I think it's perhaps clear to OP that the second sentence is just to show the difference in usage, without taking into account the change in meaning. However, if you think it necessary, please feel free to edit the example.

Answer (score 1):

> Many small companies have difficulty growing because the number of orders becomes too large to handle.

If you cross out "of orders," which is a prepositional phrase modifying "number," you see that the verb *become* is referring to *number*. Number is singular, so you would use *becomes*. "Of orders" can be safely ignored because it is a modifier:

> Typically the modifier can be removed without affecting the grammar of the sentence. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_modifier)