# Is there a term for being attracted to dead people?

Tags: meaning

Necrophilia is the act of engaging in intercourse– I'm looking for something milder. Maybe even just someone who is attracted to those who have passed. Cobain or Monroe, for example.

Comment: @Mitch HOW DARE YOU. Just Kidding. No, I prefer my bodies warm.

Comment: Attracted in what way?  How about *historian,* *anthropologist*? I realize these are not what you're after, but they, in some way, fit the criteria you've listed.  Can you refine your criteria to get at what you are really interested in?

Comment: @Jim You just said "I realize these are not what you're after". I have a sneaking suspicion that you know exactly what I'm trying to figure out but, like me, do know the word.

Comment: I'm not sure there IS a single word for this, at least not a common one.

Comment: Is this just a dead-celeb thing, or would this person be as interested in my grandmother, a seven-year-old leukemia victim, and Mark Twain as they are with Cobain and Monroe?

Comment: _Necromania_ is another word for necrophilia. [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/necromania)

Comment: @wbk, you said in another comment, "Mm, I want it specifically to mean "towards dead people", almost as if they are sacred relics." Where do you want to place the focus: on the fact that they are DEAD, which is where we have been hanging out; or on the memory of their lives?

Comment: Somehow I feel like [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/215570/a-significant-amount-of-zombies-were-detected-in-your-city) is related...

Comment: Necrophilia is not the act of engaging in intercourse.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit of a stretch, but **necromaniac** could be a possibility.

A *pyromaniac* is a lover of/has an obsession with fire.

A *nymphomaniac* is a lover of/has an obsession with sex.

A *parsinomaniac* is a lover of/has an obsession with puns and wordplay.

And so forth...

Comment: This might be an obsession with death in general, not dead people.

Comment: Not necessarily. For example, [thanatophobia](http://phobias.about.com/od/phobiaslist/a/thanatophobia.htm) is the fear of death, while [necrophobia](http://phobias.about.com/od/phobiaslist/f/What-Is-The-Fear-Of-Death-Symbols.htm) more specifically includes the fear of the dead.

Comment: Necromania is a synonym to necrophilia.

Comment: @ermanen Shout is a synonym for speak. It's a matter of degrees.

Comment: @ermanen Not by strict interpretation of the suffixes, they aren't the same at all. See ScotM's answer. If you have a source showing they are used interchangeably, please provide it.

Comment: @ermanen I never claimed this was the best answer, only that it was a possible answer that conveys the proper connotation. The simple fact is that the word the OP is looking for does not exist in common parlance, and so we have to construct it. If you have a better idea, by all means, post it as your own answer.

Comment: @ermanen Using words interchangeably is a far cry from being "exactly the same", especially when considering connotations, which is a critical consideration when choosing words. The sexual connotations make necrophilia exceedingly DIFFERENT than the more generally used necromania.

Comment: Enough already @ermanen

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to eliminate the erotic connotations of *necrophilia*, which would technically suit the purpose of your general idea, then the alternate *necromania* would probably work sufficiently. If you are willing to coin a new word, *necrolexi* would suit perfectly. It's a close call; all three could work, but *necromania* would **probably** be the best combination of **accuracy** to your idea and **connotation** for a general audience.

Of course, the root *necro* ties all three words to death and corpses by its connection to the Greek *nekros*.

In the Greek, the basic meaning of *philia* is "fondness or affection", and there is no erotic connection, (The Greek word *eros* was used for that notion.) Necrophilia was introduced into the English language as a medical term to describe a psychological disturbance which included an erotic element, but non-erotic attraction is included too. The erotic connotation has been overly emphasized in popular culture.

The Greek *mania*, on the other hand, is a "frenzy", which has been generalized by its common usage into an "obsession". Technically, necromania is an obsession with death in general, so it is not limited to corpses, but it would be an acceptable use of that word.

The Greek *elexi* is the direct translation of "attraction", but there is no common current usage of "necrolexi" in modern English. If you are speaking to a group with a technical interest in the idea, it may be worth coining a new word.

Comment: Yes, they have a broadly overlapping semantic field.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the way people are obsessed with Cobain, Monroe, JFK, Elvis, I would be inclined toward "idolatry", "celebrity-worship" or "hagiomania" for a noun or "idolize" for a verb.

Comment: Along the lines of "idolize", I'd throw "hagiofacture" in there as well.

Comment: hagiofacture is right on!

Answer (score 0):

A milder term would be **obsession** with dead celebrities.

Comment: Mm, I want it specifically to mean "towards dead people", almost as if they are sacred relics.