# Using the phrase 'a number of' with countable/uncountable nouns and verbs in singular/plural

Tags: grammatical-number, questions

Find  the mistake:

> Every year, an enormous number of paper **is** used to produce books.

My thoughts so far:

- After googling I found that when using "a number of" we use plural verb (i.e., are). Is that a general rule? In this sentence, *paper* is uncountable, so is that why we can't use "are"?
- The book's answer indicates that we can't use "a number of" with (uncountable), so we must replace it with (an amount of / a quantity of), although in [this Macmillan dictionary entry](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/number_1) *number* is described as

> [Countable / Uncountable ] a quantity of people or things

Is that right? If so, why?

Comment: Welcome to the ELU :-) - I am guessing that your book says that whatever comes **after** "a number of" should be countable - your Macmillan dictionary reference directs to whether **number** is countable.

Comment: You mean that my book is right ? but I still can't understand why a number of is wrong and an amount of is right... and do we always use are after a number of ?

Comment: Well, I think the new headline is better.

Comment: I think that replacing a number of with *a large amount of* here fits the context, because it makes sense that paper here is used as raw material for books, so to speak; on the other hand if you wanted to say: 'a number of papers go over my desk every day' you can substitute uncountable *paper* with countable, plural *papers*. As for the verb you can have a look at [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5378/a-number-of-questions-has-been-or-have-been-asked)

Comment: Paper is uncountable and when used as countable it means "newspaper" and we don't make books from newspaper

Comment: Or a sheet of [paper](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/paper)

Comment: a single sheet of paper is used to produce books, It can't be. And I am still not convinced by why a number of is wrong.

Comment: The Macmillan reference says that _number_ can be countable or uncountable. But you can _not_ use _number_ followed by an uncountable noun. _A number of paper_ is _wrong_. (_A number of papers_ is possible, but then _papers_ are countable, as in newspapers or publications. That is a different meaning altogether.)

Answer (score 1):

First off, in your example sentence, `paper` is uncountable. The expression `a number of` can only be used with countable nouns. So, your book is right. Your options are to change from `a number of` to the more suitable `a quantity/amount of`, which *can* be used with uncountable nouns.

---

Now, about the verb:

`A number of <something plural>` can't be followed by `is`

Notice that in [this Oxford entry](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/number), sense 4, it says

> A plural verb is needed after `a/an (large, small, etc.) number of`…

My guess is that since you're talking about countable things, you need to consider them all and the verb agrees with that.

Comment: So we will use a plural verb even if "A number of" is followed by singular , right ?, Although I didn't find in macmilan that a number of is specially for countables. Which identifiers comes before countables and which come before uncountables ?

Comment: @HoytVolker: A number of CANNOT be followed by singular. Anything singular is either uncountable (in which case, go for `amount`) or the singular form of a countable noun, which would be wrong. You can't say 'a number of apple'; you have to say 'a number of apples'

Comment: @HoytVolker: the error in the sentence is not the word **is**. The error is the word **number**, that should be _amount_ or _quantity_. *"a number of paper" is simply incorrect, so it is useless to discuss whether you should use a singular or plural verb.

Comment: Well, now which identifiers are followed by uncountable other than amounts and quantities ?

Comment: @HoytVolker: anything that indicates an _uncountable_ amount. _Number_ means a countable group of items, so it cannot be followed by an uncountable noun. You _can_ have bottles of water, bags of rice, amounts of wood, etcetera. There are many options, but _number_ is not one of them.

Comment: Thanks , but by the way , is " a number of" is the only special case or there is any cached one ?