# a number of children has gone to school or have gone to school

Tags: verbs, subjects

Please help, in this sentence is "a number" an attribute or the subject of the sentence?

Comment: Check this out: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5378/a-number-of-questions-has-been-or-have-been-asked

Answer (score 0):

has.  The subject of the sentence is number, in this case a collective and therefore singular noun.  We know this because the preposition "of" precedes "children", making "children" the object of a preposition and therefore not the subject.

Comment: This is incorrect. See the linked question in the comments.