# Is "an ocean of flowers" singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

'There are an ocean of flowers.' I saw this sentence in the Internet. Is it grammatically correct? I was wondering whether 'an ocean of flowers' should be treated as singular or plural.

If it is singular, then the verb should be 'is' - There is an ocean of flowers.

Apparently, the writer consider 'an ocean of flowers' a plural subject, as the verb 'are' was used. But should it be plural when the phrase starts with 'an' ('AN ocean of...')?

Thanks!

Comment: Relevant: [A number of questions “has been” or “have been” asked?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5378)

Answer (score 2):

It's an interesting construction to be sure. If it had been *a lot of*, you would not be bothered by a plural verb.

- A lot of flowers are in bloom right now.
- There are a lot of flowers in bloom right now.

The author seem to be construing *an ocean of* to be a quantifier that works the same way as *a lot of* works.   That is, it does not change the number any more than words like *some* or *many* do.

Answer (score 0):

The prescriptivist in me says you are correct and the original writer is not. "An ocean of flowers" feels much more like a visual image. Without knowing the context, I imagine something like this:
[image]

"A lot/bunch/ton of flowers" doesn't give me the same mental image.

Also, "ocean" is a countable noun. The Earth has 4 oceans: the Arctic, the Atlantic, the Indian, and the Pacific. "There are an ocean" is just offensive to my aural sensibilities.

Comment: I had the same feeling as you upon hearing this sentence. But, prescription should not be based solely on personal intuitions--that's how we get senseless peeves that don't even reflect the way educated people speak in general; they just reflect the way one person speaks. I don't think it's relevant that "ocean" is a countable noun normally. "Lot" is also a countable noun ("there's **a lot** next to my house") but we say "There are a lot of flowers."

Comment: Reading your answer, I realised that _bunch_ is rather special: _There are a bunch of flowers here_ means _There are a lot of flowers here_, whereas _There is a bunch of flowers here_ means _There is a bouquet of flowers here_.