# In layman's terms what does The O.D.O.'s definition note for the usage of the word "number" mean?

Tags: dictionaries

English is my first and only language, but when I read the Oxford Dictionary's (O.D.O.'s) definition note for the usage of the word "number" it was like I was reading an explanation meant for academics only.

Could somebody please be so kind as to water this down to layman's terms for me?

> The construction **the number of** + plural noun is used with a singular verb (as in **the number of** people affected **remains** small). Thus it is the noun **number** rather than the noun **people** which is taken to agree with the verb (and which is therefore functioning as the **head noun**). By contrast, the apparently similar construction **a number of** + plural noun is used with a plural verb (as in **a number of people remain** to be contacted). In this case it is the noun **people** which acts as the head noun and with which the verb agrees. In the latter case, **a number of** works as if it were a single word, such as **some** or **several**. See also at **lot**.

Comment: They are explaining whether to use *remain* or *remains* after *number of people*. Now try to read it again.

Comment: Is "remains" a singular verb, while "remain" a plural verb?

Comment: Yes. You would say something like "it remains" (singular) versus "they remain" (plural).

Comment: Can "the number of" ever work as if it were a single word too?

Comment: I guess I'm more interested in what does this have to do with the definition of the word "number"?

Comment: It explains how the word *number* is used in a sentence containing the expression *a/the number of [objects]*.

Comment: It's not the definition in terms of meaning of the word, it's really the usage. Basically, you don't consider the prepositional phrase "of people" when conjugating the verb. It doesn't tell you what a number is, but it tells you how to use the word on that context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A number of questions "has been" or "have been" asked?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5378/a-number-of-questions-has-been-or-have-been-asked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The excerpt from the OED describes the situation like this:

- [**the number of X**] is a singular noun phrase which takes singular agreement. The Head noun here according to the OED is the singular noun *number*:

> The number of applicants **has** increased.

---

- [**a number of X**] is a plural noun phrase which takes  plural agreement. The Head of this noun phrase is the plural noun, *X*:

> A number of applicants **have** applied for the position.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you'll find it easier to read when it's formatted as:

> The construction ***the number of + plural noun*** is used with a
>   singular verb (as in *the number of people affected remains small*).
>   Thus it is the noun *number* rather than the noun *people* which is
>   taken to agree with the verb (and which is therefore functioning as
>   the head noun).
>
> By contrast, the apparently similar construction ***a number of +
>   plural noun*** is used with a plural verb (as in *a number of people
>   remain to be contacted*). In this case it is the noun *people* which
>   acts as the head noun and with which the verb agrees. In the latter
>   case, ***a number of*** works as if it were a single word, such as
>   *some* or *several*.

Comment: Indeed, the formatting edit did help, thank you :)