# SVA: Use "is" or "are" with "an odd number of"?

Tags: verb-agreement

Which is grammatically correct? (And why?)

- (a) "There are an odd number of items in the box."
- (b) "There is an odd number of items in the box."

Comment: Closely related: [A number of questions “has been” or “have been” asked?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5378/a-number-of-questions-has-been-or-have-been-asked) I don't know if the presence of "odd" would make any difference.

Comment: @sumelic Based on that, we would say "are" is the correct one to use.

Comment: The presence of _odd_ doesn't make any difference to me. Singular agreement is equally jarring to me in both cases.

Comment: What @Janus said. A number is a number, regardless of whether it's "odd" or not. And I can't be doing with *A number are a number.*

Comment: The trouble here is that 'There are a number of ...' surely pragmatically entails four or above. But a mathematician might say 'There is/are an odd number of items in the box. One, to be precise.'

Comment: Google searches for "there is an odd number of" and "there are an odd number of" seem to indicate that the former is the more favoured. However,  "there is a number of" seems also to be preferred over "there are a number of", and I'm prescriptive enough to call this preference perverse.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the focus of your interest...

An ***odd number*** of socks ***means*** that one sock at least has gone missing.

An odd number of ***socks*** ***have*** ended up in my sock drawer.

Answer (score -2):

You want the verb to agree with "number," not "items," so the answer is (b).

It helps to turn the sentence around. "An odd number [of items] is in the box."

Number is actually the subject of the sentence, whereas "items" is the object of a preposition and does not get to determine whether verb is single or plural, "is" or "are."

Comment: Following that thinking, we should say "A lot of items is in the box"... ?

Comment: Ah, now we're into the world of collective nouns! Is it "the family is crazy" or "the family are crazy"? "The jury are out" or "The jury is out"? 

"Lot" can be singular, as in an auction, or plural. The presence of a plural noun (items) wants to push it toward plural, but my point is to remember that the subject of the sentence, not a prepositional object, determines the tense of the verb.

Comment: @ChasS.Clifton That's not collective nouns as such. Certain quantifies (a lot of, a number of, a host of, a group of, etc.) generally take plural agreement despite being morphologically singular. _An odd number of_ is one of those. To me (and many others) “There is an odd number of items is in the box” and “An odd number of items is in the box” are both highly jarring.

Comment: @Janus So you prefer to be guided by a principle of "countability." That's fine.

Comment: As @tchrist has said: 'We are looking for more substantial answers with documented references, not merely [statements that may possibly be no more than] personal opinion. Those are just comments, not answers.' // One such reference is [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/number-of-people-is-or-are), which has 'Although the expression ‘a number’ is strictly singular, the phrase ‘a number of’' is used with plural nouns (as what grammarians call a determiner ... ). The verb should therefore be plural....'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If you submit that as an answer, I will make it the accepted answer.  The ODO reference is extremely convincing, especially as I read more about grammar rules and definitions concerning determiners.

Comment: @Pistos Agreement with 'a number of' has already been covered on ELU. The only reason I haven't close-voted this question is because I'm not entirely convinced that 'an odd number of' behaves in exactly the same way. See sumelic's commendable comment.