# "A number" vs "the number"

Tags: articles, verb-agreement, definite-articles

1. The **number** of students is large.
2. The number of **students** are absent.
3. A number of **students** are absent.

We easily see that:

- in sentence (1), "**The number** of students", we refer to **"the number"**, so verb is in singular form.
- in sentence (2) - "The number of **students**" and sentence (3) - "A number of **students**", we refer to **"students"**, so verbs are in plural form.

But I don't know what is the difference between "The number of students" in sentence (2) and "A number of students" in sentence (3).

When you see or hear them, what would you think? What arises in your mind?
In what context can we us "The number of **students**" or "A number of **students**"?

I hope to receive your advice. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You could say, “the number of students [that are] absent is large” or “the number of students is missing” (meaning that the value stating the number of students - e.g. In a table- is blank)  but as written #2 doesn’t make any sense.

Comment: The meaning of "*A number* of students are absent" is that we may have no exact tally, but are pointing to a notable percentage of missing students. By itself, version #2 doesn't hold together in the same way.  Maybe "The number of students absent today **is** notable (singular).  The reason 'a number of students' is plural relies not on students (plural), but on understanding that it means many students -- certainly more than one -- so we use plural.

Comment: This is a duplicate question (apart from the ungrammatical suggestion), but I can't find a decent answer.

Comment: Jim, please, what's the difference between *are absent* and *is missing*, other than plurality?

Comment: Yosef, please, what’s the difference between *a number of students is plural* and * many students -- certainly more than one -- so we use plural*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A number of questions "has been" or "have been" asked?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5378/a-number-of-questions-has-been-or-have-been-asked)

Answer (score 1):

The most primitive difference is that "The number of students are absent" is unacceptable English, but "A number of students are absent" is acceptable.

The phrase ***the*** number of X is always singular and takes a verb inflected for third person singular. In this construction *of X* is merely a complement or modifier (depending on your grammatical sect) of *the number*, and *the number* is a definite noun phrase meaning a specific number considered as an entity: the actual count of X.

The phrase ***a*** number of X is always<sup>†</sup> plural and takes a verb inflected for plural. In this construction *a number*, although it looks like a noun phrase, is actually a quantifier, a sort of determiner meaning approximately "several". *Of X* is its complement or head nominal (again depending on your grammatical sect); *X* is cast in the plural and that plurality "percolates up" through the determiner to govern the number of the verb. ("Percolates up" is the apt metaphor employed by *CGEL*, which calls nouns used this way, such as *number* and *lot/s* and *bunch*, "non-count quantificational nouns".)

---

<sup>†</sup> <sub>Well, ***almost*** always. It is possible for *a number of X* to occur with a singular *X*. For instance: *Most texts of* Revelation *give the Number of the Beast as 666, but a few give 616. Pick **a number** of the Beast you like and give a plausible interpretation of that.* In this case, *a number* is again a noun phrase and *of the Beast* its complement/modifier. But it took me a lot of effort to invent a legitimate instance of this practically very rare situation.</sub>

Comment: Is it just me, or does that pass the Question by? I don't understand how plurality, or the actual number, could matter…

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin The first actual Question is "What is the difference between *A/The number of students are absent*?" I answer that in my first sentence. The followup is "When do we use *A/The number of students*?", to which the remainder of my answer is addressed: *The number* designates a count, *A number* is a quantifier meaning "several".

Comment: Thanks StoneyB. I thought the questions meant why is *the number of students are/is absent* wrong and why is *a number of students are/is absent* correct.

Either way I don't understand how plurality, or actual number, could matter

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin *The number of X* is always singular, *a number of X* is virtually always plural, because they have different syntactic functions.

Comment: Thanks and how does that relate to the problem. please?

The number of students are/is absent is certainly not wrong because of plurality and prolly not because of specificity.

A number of students are/is absent is not certainly not corrrect because of plurality and prolly not because of generality.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin ANY clause starting *The number are* is unacceptable, because *the number* is a singular noun; but *The number of X **is** absent* could be acceptable because it denotes the absence of the number, not the students: "The number of students is absent from this table." *A number of students are X* is syntactically acceptable because *A number of* is a plural quantifier; whether it is semantically acceptable depends on the semantic compatibility of *X* and *students*.

Comment: If the problem was *The number are* then why would *The number is* fail, please? However tightly you define it, that still seems like a different point.

*The number of X is absent* could be grammatically acceptable because it denoted the absence of the number, not the students, and how would that relate to the question, please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin  I'm not grasping what your objection is, so I suspect we're starting from very different understandings of what this question is about. Let's take it in another direction, then: what is it you think I **should** be addressing?

Comment: Thanks for your patience and I'm not objecting… just failing to understand.

I hope I don’t seem a hijacker and to me it seems that although what Napole in fact asked was indeed *what's the difference* and *In what context*, the actual point is not plurality or even number, but the difference between *large* and *absent* and the verb forms that follow that…

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I may be reading more into the question than is there; but in my experience here, the difficulty learners have with these "non-count quantificational nouns" is that 1) there is an apparent contradiction between the singular noun *number*, which looks like the head of the phrase "**a** number of X", and the plural form of the verb it takes; but 2) this contradiction disappears when *number* takes the definite article.