# Which role does the noun "number" play in the phrase ‘a number of ’?

Tags: grammar

I am confused with the role of the noun *number* in the phrase ‘a number of ’.

Is the noun *number* a quantifier here or a collective noun?
Some people argue that the number is a quantifier in ["A number" vs "the number"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/392949/a-number-vs-the-number).
However, some people argue that the number is a collective noun in https://www.dictionary.com/browse/collective-noun.

Comment: It's best to regard _a number of_ as a compound (formed of/from more than one word) quantifier, like _ink well_ (= _inkwell_) is always regarded as a compound noun. [This article from the University of Bristol](http://www.bristol.ac.uk/academic-language/media/BEAP/1.4/index.html) is one of many endorsing this analysis. // While it's obvious what parts of speech 'a', 'number', and 'of' typically are, it's not worthwhile to break down the fixed expression 'a number of'.

Comment: Thanks for your help very much.

Comment: Within the idiom *a number*, *number* is a number transparent quantificational noun. Notice both that *of* is not part of this idiom and that *a number* is a two word noun phrase not a single word. You can stick any appropriate adjectives or other modifiers inside it. “Only a disappointingly small number are actually registered”, for example.

Comment: Thans for your help, Araucaria.