# Singular or plural verb with "A series of"

Tags: grammar

should a verb after the phrase "a series of" be singular or plural?

- A series of incidents **has** taken place since the accident.
- A series of incidents **have** taken place since the accident.

Comment: [A number of questions **has** been asked here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5378/a-number-of-questions-has-been-or-have-been-asked) before about this issue.

Comment: I'd treat 'a series of' as a number-transparent quantifier and use 'have' here (compare 'a score of incidents have taken place ...') rather than formal agreement; [these Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+series+of+incidents+has%2Ca+series+of+incidents+have&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20series%20of%20incidents%20has%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20series%20of%20incidents%20have%3B%2Cc0) seem to show that opinion remains divided.