# The maximum number of active participants HAS exceeded or IS exceeded?

Tags: word-choice, verb-forms

For the following text:

The input shows an invalid red error box if the maximum number of active participants ___ exceeded.

What should go in the ___ ?

Some options that I can think of are:

- Is
- Has

I am curious if there is an option above that is incorrect grammatically?

Comment: This question has been marked as a duplicate of another question ("[A number of questions “has been” or “have been” asked?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5378/a-number-of-questions-has-been-or-have-been-asked)"), but the other question is completely unrelated to this one. This question asks whether the correct verb to use is "is", "has", or something else; the other question asks whether the phrase "a number of questions" is singular or plural.

Comment: @TannerSwett The virtue of the linked question is that it least gives a solution to what to go in the blank. Even if not linked to that question, this question should be closed. It currently lacks research, and is a request for ideas or suggestions, and a request for proofreading, which are out of our scope.

Comment: When a question asks for proofreading or rewriting (“how should I write this?”, “is this correct?”, “which is correct?”), that is out of scope for this site and may be removed. See: “[What topics can I ask about here? - Help Center](/help/on-topic)”. If there is an unstated specific concern, such as “What does (word) mean in context?” or “How does (grammar or punctuation rule) apply in context?” try asking that question instead. Also check out: “[Where can I ask for free proofreading? – Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7571)”.

Comment: @MetaEd Please consider changing the close reason from "duplicate" to "off topic".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either word, but if you use *has*, you need to make a slight change.

> If the maximum number of active participants *is* exceeded.
>   If the maximum number of active participants *has* ***been*** exceeded.

Comment: These both work because they are passive.  "has exceeded" fails because 'to exceed' is normally transitive and the clause has no direct object.